# Реализация размытия фона для electron приложения

Tags: electron, app, blur

Как понятно из заголовка, мне хочется размыть фон для приложения

Может ли электрон мне такое позволить ?

Костыли с opacity не подойдут. Нужен результат как у окон самой винды, или сторонних приложений - на примере яндекс музыки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если и нет возможности такое реализовать, подскажете, пожалуйста, чем можно достичь столь желанный эффект.

Comment: Возможно это? https://github.com/seo-rii/electron-acrylic-window

Comment: Хотя я чего-то не понял: если вопрос про electron, то при чём тут метка python?

Comment: Извиняюсь, случайно прописал. Но похоже это то, что мне нужно. Вы мой спаситель